# Integer to binary with haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary

I'm having trouble with this function, i need it to give the binary form of a number as a list of 4 elemnts ( just from 0 to 15) 
so for example  for the input 0 it should give me [0,0,0,0], 3 : [0,0,1,1] , 15 [1,1,1,1]
so that's what i did

```
bin 0 x = []
bin n x = (mod x 2) : (bin (n-1) (div x 2))
```

It gives the result in backwards 
and this :

```
bin 0 x = []
bin n x =  (bin (n-1) (div x 2)) ++ (mod x 2)
```

don't work, when compiling it doesn't show an error, but when i enter for example `bin 4 1` it shows :

```
"No instance fo ( Integral [t0]) arising from a use of 'it'
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command : print it "
```

I can't figure out what to do, any help will be appreciated

Comment: try to add type signatures for your function - that increases the helpfulness of error messages - also think what `mod x 2` is and what it should be if you use it with `(++)` (hint try to use those square brackets)

Comment: Thank you @epsilonhalbe i realise now that ++ is used between 2 lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++` takes two lists and `mod x 2` is not a list. You can use

```
... ++ [mod x 2]
```

However, be warned that repeatedly adding an element at the end of a list like that is inefficient, leading to quadratic complexity.

It's better to use your first snippet which produces the bits backwards and then using `reverse` to rearrange the bits in the forward direction at the end. This will provide linear complexity.